# Stop QScrollArea items from jumping around when adding new items through textinput

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I have a simple `QScrollarea` that has a `QWidget` with a vertical box layout inside that contains a lot of widgets. I'm adding new widgets to it after mouse clicks and after text inputs in a QLineEdit.

However the scrollarea behaves differently depending on what caused an insert of a new item. If my `addTestLabel()` gets called after a `textChanged()` signal the whole contents jump around for a second, however if the same `addTestLabel()` is called from a mouseclick event it works exactly as it should, which doesn't make sense to me.

Gif example, at first I insert items by clicking and it works perfectly, then I start inserting by typing and it jumps around. Then I go back to clicking and it jumps after the first click but then all further clicks insert without jumping again

[image]

Shortest minimal example I could make:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QLineEdit

from ui.tabdock.utils import *


class ChatView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #make the main window a vertical box layout
        self._boxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._boxLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.setLayout(self._boxLayout)


        # make a scroll area and put it at the top
        self._scrollArea =  QScrollArea()
        self._scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self._boxLayout.addWidget(self._scrollArea)

        # add a text input below the scroll area
        self._textInput = QLineEdit()

        # make it add a new item every time textChange event fires
        #THIS RESULTS IN EVERYTHING JUMPING FOR A SECOND
        self._textInput.textChanged.connect(lambda t: self.addTestLabel("text change add")) 

        self._boxLayout.addWidget(self._textInput)

        # make a container view with a vertical box layout that will contain all the actual items
        self.listContainerView = QWidget()
        self.listContainerView.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.listContainerView.layout().setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        # put the container view inside the scroll area
        self._scrollArea.setWidget(self.listContainerView)

        #some items to get started
        for i in range(10):
            self.addTestLabel("label %s"%i)

        #add new items whenever the mouse is pressed somewhere
        # THIS INSERTS CORRECTLY WITHOUT JUMPING
        self.mousePressEvent = lambda e:self.addTestLabel() 

    def addTestLabel(self, text = "complex widget goes here"):
        label = QLabel(text)
        label.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;")
        label.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.listContainerView.layout().addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cv = ChatView()
    cv.show()
    cv.setGeometry(400,400,1200,800)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I stop the split second of jumping around if `addTestLabel()` is called from the `textChanged` signal and make it behave like when it's called from the mouseclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was that whenever the scrollarea and its containerview were not in focus, like when I was typing in the textbox and that had focus, it would not instantly update the geometry and layout after adding something to the container widget so it would look weird for a second until it got around to update it.

Just adding `self.listContainerView.updateGeometry()` after adding the widgets to force a layout refresh fixed it.